# QBitArray shift

Tags: c++, qt, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

How can I shift a QBitArray in QT?

For example, I have *0010000* which I'd like to shift left, so I would get *0100000*. There is no function for this in [QT's documentation](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qbitarray.html) concerning QBitArray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QBitArray's purpose is using it for bitmasks of arbitrary sizes, not for arithmetic operations. You cannot shift a QBitArray. If you think you need to shift a QBitArray, then chances are you are abusing this class rather than using it.

Comment: Yeah, I might be abusing it and so far it came in handy :) Just thought It was possible in some way. Which container do you propose then?

Comment: @PrimožKralj Just use a std::bitset.

Comment: Thanks, it really suits my needs better.